# Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port #####: Connection refused (RSelenium error)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am learning about RSelenium.

**Does anyone have a solution for this error:**
`Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port #####: Connection refused`.

I am surprised by the localpost port error given the use of `netstat` package so think it might have to do with the driver versions?

I have checked my chrome version with [chrome://version/](https://chrome://version/). My version is not listed in the options when I run:
`binman::list_versions("chromedriver")`. Mine is a newer version. When I paste in `chromever = 'version closest to mine'` or when I leave it as the default, it fails in either case. Other browsers used for the argument `browser = "firefox"` etc. have failed.

Here is the code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)

# Server ----------------------------------------------
binman::list_versions("seleniumserver")

rs_driver_var <-
  rsDriver(browser = "chrome",verbose = FALSE, port = free_port())

# Create a client driver --------------------------------------------------

remDr <- rs_driver_var$client

# Open a browser ----------------------------------------------------------

remDr$open()
```

If you can assist, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Was there a number in place of the hashes in the error message? Or is the error message exactly what R returned?

Comment: Not sure what's going on with `firefox`, but regarding Chrome and chomerdiver, there's still this open issue - https://github.com/ropensci/wdman/issues/34 . You can opt for workarounds (i.e. manually installing up to date chromedriver) or try out related pull request - https://github.com/ropensci/wdman/pull/39

Comment: @stevec hi, thank you for your reply. There was a number listed for the port.

Comment: @margusl thank you for your reply. I think I’d need to revert Chrome to an older version to match the one in the binman. I was hoping to avoid that as I think I had read somewhere that my cookies and settings would not be as they are now. May try the GitHub link this week. Though, not sure it’s a driver location issue. It may be a good start. Thank you again.